# Losing entries when inner-joining data to a left-joined DataFrame in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to join data with a DataFrame that in turn resulted from a left join. While in batch processing this works as expected, in stream processing some entries are lost...

Below I created a minimal example of "sessions", that have "start" and "end" events and optionally some "metadata".

The script generates two outputs: `sessionStartsWithMetadata` result from "start" events that are left-joined with the "metadata" events, based on `sessionId`. A "left join" is used, since we like to get an output event even when no corresponding metadata exists.

Additionally a DataFrame `endedSessionsWithMetadata` is created by joining "end" events to the previously created DataFrame. Here an "inner join" is used, since we only want some output when a session has ended for sure.

This code can be executed in `spark-shell`:

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.{MemoryStream, StreamingQueryWrapper}
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, expr, lit}

import spark.implicits._
implicit val sqlContext: SQLContext = spark.sqlContext

// Main data processing, regardless whether batch or stream processing
def process(
    sessionStartEvents: DataFrame,
    sessionOptionalMetadataEvents: DataFrame,
    sessionEndEvents: DataFrame
): (DataFrame, DataFrame) = {
  val sessionStartsWithMetadata: DataFrame = sessionStartEvents
    .join(
      sessionOptionalMetadataEvents,
      sessionStartEvents("sessionId") === sessionOptionalMetadataEvents("sessionId") &&
        sessionStartEvents("sessionStartTimestamp").between(
          sessionOptionalMetadataEvents("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp").minus(expr(s"INTERVAL 1 seconds")),
          sessionOptionalMetadataEvents("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp").plus(expr(s"INTERVAL 1 seconds"))
        ),
      "left" // metadata is optional
    )
    .select(
      sessionStartEvents("sessionId"),
      sessionStartEvents("sessionStartTimestamp"),
      sessionOptionalMetadataEvents("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp")
    )

  val endedSessionsWithMetadata = sessionStartsWithMetadata.join(
    sessionEndEvents,
    sessionStartsWithMetadata("sessionId") === sessionEndEvents("sessionId") &&
      sessionStartsWithMetadata("sessionStartTimestamp").between(
        sessionEndEvents("sessionEndTimestamp").minus(expr(s"INTERVAL 10 seconds")),
        sessionEndEvents("sessionEndTimestamp")
      )
  )

  (sessionStartsWithMetadata, endedSessionsWithMetadata)
}

def streamProcessing(
    sessionStartData: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)],
    sessionOptionalMetadata: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)],
    sessionEndData: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)]
): (StreamingQuery, StreamingQuery) = {

  val sessionStartEventsStream: MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)] = MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)]
  sessionStartEventsStream.addData(sessionStartData)

  val sessionStartEvents: DataFrame = sessionStartEventsStream
    .toDS()
    .toDF("sessionStartTimestamp", "sessionId")
    .withWatermark("sessionStartTimestamp", "1 second")

  val sessionOptionalMetadataEventsStream: MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)] = MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)]
  sessionOptionalMetadataEventsStream.addData(sessionOptionalMetadata)

  val sessionOptionalMetadataEvents: DataFrame = sessionOptionalMetadataEventsStream
    .toDS()
    .toDF("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp", "sessionId")
    .withWatermark("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp", "1 second")

  val sessionEndEventsStream: MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)] = MemoryStream[(Timestamp, Int)]
  sessionEndEventsStream.addData(sessionEndData)

  val sessionEndEvents: DataFrame = sessionEndEventsStream
    .toDS()
    .toDF("sessionEndTimestamp", "sessionId")
    .withWatermark("sessionEndTimestamp", "1 second")

  val (sessionStartsWithMetadata, endedSessionsWithMetadata) =
    process(sessionStartEvents, sessionOptionalMetadataEvents, sessionEndEvents)

  val sessionStartsWithMetadataQuery = sessionStartsWithMetadata
    .select(lit("sessionStartsWithMetadata"), col("*")) // Add label to see which query's output it is
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", "false")
    .option("numRows", "1000")
    .start()

  val endedSessionsWithMetadataQuery = endedSessionsWithMetadata
    .select(lit("endedSessionsWithMetadata"), col("*")) // Add label to see which query's output it is
    .writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", "false")
    .option("numRows", "1000")
    .start()

  (sessionStartsWithMetadataQuery, endedSessionsWithMetadataQuery)
}

def batchProcessing(
    sessionStartData: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)],
    sessionOptionalMetadata: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)],
    sessionEndData: Seq[(Timestamp, Int)]
): Unit = {

  val sessionStartEvents = spark.createDataset(sessionStartData).toDF("sessionStartTimestamp", "sessionId")
  val sessionOptionalMetadataEvents = spark.createDataset(sessionOptionalMetadata).toDF("sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp", "sessionId")
  val sessionEndEvents = spark.createDataset(sessionEndData).toDF("sessionEndTimestamp", "sessionId")

  val (sessionStartsWithMetadata, endedSessionsWithMetadata) =
    process(sessionStartEvents, sessionOptionalMetadataEvents, sessionEndEvents)

  println("sessionStartsWithMetadata")
  sessionStartsWithMetadata.show(100, truncate = false)

  println("endedSessionsWithMetadata")
  endedSessionsWithMetadata.show(100, truncate = false)
}


// Data is represented as tuples of (eventTime, sessionId)...
val sessionStartData = Vector(
  (new Timestamp(1), 0),
  (new Timestamp(2000), 1),
  (new Timestamp(2000), 2),
  (new Timestamp(20000), 10)
)

val sessionOptionalMetadata = Vector(
  (new Timestamp(1), 0),
  // session `1` has no metadata
  (new Timestamp(2000), 2),
  (new Timestamp(20000), 10)
)

val sessionEndData = Vector(
  (new Timestamp(10000), 0),
  (new Timestamp(11000), 1),
  (new Timestamp(12000), 2),
  (new Timestamp(30000), 10)
)

batchProcessing(sessionStartData, sessionOptionalMetadata, sessionEndData)

val (sessionStartsWithMetadataQuery, endedSessionsWithMetadataQuery) =
  streamProcessing(sessionStartData, sessionOptionalMetadata, sessionEndData)
```

In the example session with ID `1` has no metadata, so the respective metadata column is `null`.

The main functionality of joining the data is implemented in `def process(…)`, which is called using both batch data and stream data.

In the batch version the output is as expected:

```
sessionStartsWithMetadata
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+            
|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp  |sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+
|0        |1970-01-01 01:00:00.001|1970-01-01 01:00:00.001         |
|1        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |null                            | ← has no metadata ✔
|2        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |1970-01-01 01:00:02             |
|10       |1970-01-01 01:00:20    |1970-01-01 01:00:20             |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+

endedSessionsWithMetadata
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp  |sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|sessionEndTimestamp|sessionId|
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|0        |1970-01-01 01:00:00.001|1970-01-01 01:00:00.001         |1970-01-01 01:00:10|0        |
|1        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |null                            |1970-01-01 01:00:11|1        |  ← has no metadata ✔
|2        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |1970-01-01 01:00:02             |1970-01-01 01:00:12|2        |
|10       |1970-01-01 01:00:20    |1970-01-01 01:00:20             |1970-01-01 01:00:30|10       |
+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
```

But when the same processing is run as stream processing the output of `endedSessionsWithMetadata` does not contain the entry of session `1` that has no metadata:

```
-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 0 ("start event")
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp  |sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|10       |1970-01-01 01:00:20    |1970-01-01 01:00:20             |
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|2        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |1970-01-01 01:00:02             |
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|0        |1970-01-01 01:00:00.001|1970-01-01 01:00:00.001         |
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+

-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 0 ("end event")
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|endedSessionsWithMetadata|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp  |sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|sessionEndTimestamp|sessionId|
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|endedSessionsWithMetadata|10       |1970-01-01 01:00:20    |1970-01-01 01:00:20             |1970-01-01 01:00:30|10       |
|endedSessionsWithMetadata|2        |1970-01-01 01:00:02    |1970-01-01 01:00:02             |1970-01-01 01:00:12|2        |
|endedSessionsWithMetadata|0        |1970-01-01 01:00:00.001|1970-01-01 01:00:00.001         |1970-01-01 01:00:10|0        |
+-------------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+

-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 1 ("start event")
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp|sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+
|sessionStartsWithMetadata|1        |1970-01-01 01:00:02  |null                            | ← has no metadata ✔
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+

-------------------------------------------                                     
Batch: 1 ("end event")
-------------------------------------------
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
|endedSessionsWithMetadata|sessionId|sessionStartTimestamp|sessionOptionalMetadataTimestamp|sessionEndTimestamp|sessionId|
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
+-------------------------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------+-------------------+---------+
  ↳ ✘ here I would have expected a line with sessionId=1, that has "start" and "end" information, but no "metadata" ✘
```

Can anybody explain why in stream processing the "end" event with no "metadata" (`sessionId=1`) is not there? What do I need to do to make it appear in the output?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the effect if you have watermark 5 seconds?

Comment: I'm on on holidays so I am not getting too heavy into it.

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks for looking at this! Unfortunately a 5sec watermark doesn't change the result.

Comment: My comment above was not valid. back from hols. Ran it and a little curious. Consulting manuals. Will do some experimenting tomorrow.

Comment: This returned nothing: ...        sessionEndEvents("sessionEndTimestamp"),
        sessionEndEvents("sessionEndTimestamp").plus(expr(s"INTERVAL 10 seconds"))

Comment: I have tried numerous combinations but cannot get it to gen that data either. Interesting. I did see some aspects on Spark issues but you have global watermark. Any advancement your side. All the examples are with 2 tables in general although I did find one with 3 tables.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I couldn't find any way to get correct output either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable testing, looking around and re-reading the manual:

> - It must be a bug in Spark.
> - I note also this post in circulation: https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/cc6489a19316e7382661d305fabd8c21915e5faf6a928b4869ac2b4a@%3Cdev.spark.apache.org%3E
>   and whilst global vs chained stream-stream joins are understood, this
>   point imo to an issue for this type of processing.
> - I ran on Spark Databricks 3.x to no avail.

Comment: Thanks you for the mailing list post. Unfortunately it really appears to be a limitation of Spark.

Comment: But not evident from the manuals. Although they only show a JOIN of 2 DS, DFs only. Anyway we r in the no now.

Comment: Good question in any event.

Comment: With the above remarks a Spark ticket has been created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-33259